# Cloud functions errors - where to look for Google FrontEnd error logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I've got a bunch of cloud functions running on Firebase. Since yesterday, customers are saying they're getting intermittent `500 - Server Error` responses, but there's nothing in the firebase functions logs neither in stack driver logs.

The error is responded as html:

```
<html>
...
<title>500 Server Error</title>
...
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds</h2>
...
```

In the response headers, I see "Server: Google Frontend".

I'm not sure if it's a proxy error or whether the request is being delivered or not to the cloud functions; logs are all clean.

Where do I check to see if it's a proxy error or any other cloud component misbehaving? Are there logs for Google Frontend?

Comment: There's little information on your problem but if the issue persists and there's still no actionable messages on your logs, I suggest creating a ticket by contacting Firebase Support https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Answer (score 1):

Google Front End (GFE) is a Google layer (not Google Cloud only, I mean the whole google!) that is in front of the web to accept the request. It's a proxy with a lot of feature such as filter, SSL/TLS serving, load balancing,...

When you deploy a Cloud Function for example, it is not directly deployed on the internet, always behind GFE

[image]

Thus, it's always GFE that answer you, for good and bad request. There is no error 500 on GFE, it's only a proxy. The error 500 is in your code, GFE only forward the Cloud Functions error code to the client, and has added his own header.

Comment: Great clarification, thanks! So I guess these errors are just not being logged, is it possible?

Comment: I mean, the errors happen intermittently on random GET routes, pile up for around 20 minutes, then stop - but I only know that because of my client's logs, there are 0 errors in gcloud's logs. Happened twice yesterday after months of total API stability.

Comment: Products are always updated in background, I recommend  you to open a case to the support, It's maybe a bad Google Cloud release.